# How to insert a new element after an element by using the selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to ask how can I add a new element after a specific element after the button is clicked.

Here's my sample code:

```html
    <table id="table-1" border="1" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>TITLE</td>
                <td>TITLE</td>
                <td>TITLE</td>
                <td>TITLE</td>
                <td>TITLE</td>    
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="no-row">
            <td colspan="5">no content</td>
        </tbody>            
                    
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">footer</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>    
    </table>
    <button id="add-row">Add Row</button>
```

I have this simple jquery:

```js
$('#add-row').on('click', function(){
        var counter = 1;
        var add_row = '<tbody>';
            add_row += '<tr>';
            add_row += '  <td>' + counter + '</td>';
            add_row += '  <td></td>';
            add_row += '  <td></td>';
            add_row += '  <td></td>';
            add_row += '  <td></td>';
            add_row += '</tr>';         
            add_row += '</tbody>';   
        
        $('#table-1 #no-row').remove();
        
        $('#table-1 thead').append(add_row);
                     
        counter++;             
                     
    });
```

But it just appending it inside the thead.

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rochellecanale/gov88ucm/1/

Comment: You can use `.after()` in jQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`append()` inserts the specified content *within* the selected element. To insert it after the element use the `after()` method instead:

```
$('#table-1 thead').after(add_row);
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gov88ucm/2/)

> how can i display the newest added row to the bottom?

You can select the `tfoot` and use `before()`:

```
$('#table-1 tfoot').before(add_row);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gov88ucm/3/)

Comment: Thanks. Ok I tried that but how can i display the newest added row to the bottom?

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

Change     `$('#table-1 thead').append(add_row);` to     `$('#table-1').append(add_row);`

```
var counter = 1;
$('#add-row').on('click', function(){
    var add_row = '<tbody>';
        add_row += '<tr>';
        add_row += '  <td>' + counter + '</td>';
        add_row += '  <td></td>';
        add_row += '  <td></td>';
        add_row += '  <td></td>';
        add_row += '  <td></td>';
        add_row += '</tr>';         
        add_row += '</tbody>';   

    $('#table-1 #no-row').remove();

    $('#table-1').append(add_row);

    counter++;             

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `after` keyword. The after keyword Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$('#table-1 thead').after(add_row);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<tbody>` is missing a `<tr>`

```
<tbody>
  <tr id="no-row">
    <td colspan="5">no content</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

change your add_row to remove `tbody` then append directly to the `tbody`

```
$('#table-1 #no-row').remove();
$('#table-1>tbody').append(add_row)
```

this way, your append function is re-usable as you're currently re-adding the tbody every time.

To answer the question specifically, you can add the ID to `tr` as above, remove `tbody` from `add_row` and add after the `no-row`:

```
$('#table-1 #no-row').hide();
$('#table-1 #no-row').after(add_row)
```